# HTTP Requests from an unknown source

Tags: security, web-server

A web server I operate has recently been targeted with unknown HTTP requests originating from China. They all occurred within seconds of each other, so I believe they were automated. They were also structured in an unusual way.

Here's an example:

```
[2020-08-14-04-10-24]: (::ffff:182.138.137.219) requested (/-----https://www.google.com/) from (liitl.cf) with status code 404
[2020-08-14-04-10-33]: (::ffff:175.152.28.4) requested (/-----https://www.facebook.com/) from (liitl.cf) with status code 404
[2020-08-14-04-23-39]: (::ffff:221.13.12.28) requested (/-----https://www.google.com/) from (kcgdchat.cf) with status code 404
[2020-08-14-04-23-39]: (::ffff:49.118.201.193) requested (/-----https://www.google.com/) from (auth.kcgdnetwork.cf) with status code 404
[2020-08-14-04-23-39]: (::ffff:223.193.213.55) requested (/-----http://dongtaiwang.com) from (undefined) with status code 404
```

Here is a normal request for reference:

```
[2020-08-02-13-29-40]: (::ffff:192.168.1.1) requested (/r/) from (liitl.cf) with status code 200
```

Does anyone know what these are?

Comment: They appear (attempted) proxy requests. Attempts to abuse an incorrectly configured web server as an open proxy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy

Comment: And malformed, so someone probably doesn't know what they're doing. Or it's meant to attack a very unusual software configuration. BTW, your log entries look very strange.